# Changing graphics backend for unit testing

Tags: r, ggplot2, ragg

I have an R-package containing a function that generates a plot that relies on the AGG graphics backend to draw emoji. However, when I include this function in the unit tests, the tests fail because I can't set the AGG graphics backend (correctly) in the test environment. Tests need to pass to stay on CRAN.

On my machine, I can do it manually by going to `Tools > Global options > General > Graphics > Backend > AGG`. When I try to set this manually, I get the following error: `Error in 'grid.newpage()': no active or default device`

Here's what I tried so far:

```
test_that("Plotting Emoji", {

  OldDevice <- getOption("device")
  options(device = "AGG")

 # generating the ggplot2 and some data, do tests on the data

 options(device = OldDevice)

}
```

Is it possible to change the device temporarily from a script? If so, how would I do it and should this be done in the testing script or the function itself? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: [This](https://withr.r-lib.org/reference/defer.html) is not a complete answer, but will most likely be helpful.

Comment: @Limey I don’t think that’s related. OP wants to execute the relevant code *in the current scope*, not in a parent scope, but it doesn’t work for unrelated reasons. (Admittedly OP’s code could still be improved but a better solution would then be to use `withr::local_options()`, not `withr::defer()`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  My bad.  I meant to refer to `withr` generally, not `withr::defer` specifically.  Thanks for the clarification/correction.